# How to call data/variable from a python module?

Tags: python

I created a python module in which I stored a variable. when I run: `help(connections_and_variables.connections_and_variables)`

I can see in the "DATA" section the variable (dw_path).

How can I call this in the script that reads the module?

```
NAME
    connections_and_variables.connections_and_variables - Created on Fri Jun 15 10:19:46 2018

FILE
    c:\users\USER\documents\data-warehouse\connections_and_variables\connections_and_variables.py

DESCRIPTION
    @author: USER

FUNCTIONS
    db(name)

    db_engine(name)

DATA
    dw_path = r'C:\Users\USER\Documents\data-warehouse'
```

Comment: `dw_path` is just another attribute on that module. Help groups objects in a module by type, and `dw_path` is a string, not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you would access anything else from a module:

```
import connections_and_variables.connections_and_variables
print(connections_and_variables.connections_and_variables.dw_path)
```

Or:

```
from connections_and_variables import connections_and_variables
print(connections_and_variables.dw_path)
```

Or:

```
from connections_and_variables.connections_and_variables import dw_path
print(dw_path)
```